# Alternative to using async () => in Rx Finally

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive

My understanding is that `async void`, [should be avoided](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and that `async () =>`  is just `async void` in disguise when used with `Action`.

Hence, using [the Rx.NET Finally operator](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html) asynchronously with `async () =>`  should be avoided since Finally accepts `Action` as parameter:

```
IObservable<T>.Finally(async () =>
{
    await SomeCleanUpCodeAsync();
};
```

However, if this is bad practise, what is then best practice to use in the case where I for instance need to **asynchronously** close a network connection on OnCompleted or if my observable end with OnError?

Comment: The async lambdas you've shown here are `async void` methods, but not all async lambdas are going to be `void` methods.  If you provide an async lambda in a context where a `Task` returning method is expected, that's what you'll get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that async void, should be avoided and that `async
>   () =>` is just `async void` in disguise.

This is partially wrong. `async () =>` can either match `Func<Task>` (good) or `Action` (bad). The main reason for good/bad is that an exception that occurs in a `async void` call crashes the process, whereas a `async Task` exception is catchable.

So we just need to write an `AsyncFinally` operator that takes in a `Func<Task>` instead of an `Action` like `Observable.Finally`:

```
public static class X
{
    public static IObservable<T> AsyncFinally<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<Task> action)
    {
        return source
            .Materialize()
            .SelectMany(async n =>
            {
                switch (n.Kind)
                {
                    case NotificationKind.OnCompleted:
                    case NotificationKind.OnError:
                        await action();
                        return n;
                    case NotificationKind.OnNext:
                        return n;
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            })
            .Dematerialize()
        ;
    }
}
```

And here's a demonstration of usage:

```
try
{
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .Take(10)
        .AsyncFinally(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        })
        .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught, no problem");
}
```

If you swap out `AsyncFinally` for `Finally`, you'll crash the process.

Comment: I really like this approach. I was not familiar with Materialize/Dematerialize. Nice way of using them. But why use SelectMany and not just Select?

Comment: Select won't work there. The async selector function with select would turn it from `IObservable<Notification<T>>` into `IObservable<Task<Notification<T>>`. The SelectMany version flattens out the Task part of that.

Comment: If I Dispose of the subscription OnCompleted or OnError will not occure and hence the SomeCleanUpCodeAsync will not run. I thought it would. Am I doing something wrong or is there a work-around?

Comment: No, that is intended functionality. Workaround would be explicitly calling the clean up when you dispose the subscription. Alternatively, you could use Observable.Using.

Comment: Ok, but how then do I run the clean up as async? `Disposable.Create` is like Finally in the the sense that it expects an `Action` rather than a Func<Task>. Is there a way to create a Disposable.AsyncCreate that will call DisposeAsync, or something like this. Maybe I should create a seperate question for this?

Comment: I would create a separate question.

Comment: You are right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286998/async-disposable-create

Comment: Noted that this solution doesn't work on `subscription.Dispose()`. the action in `AsynFinally` will be missed if you dispose the observable before completed.

Answer (score 2):

It is in Rx as it is elsewhere; avoid `async void` like the plague. In addition to the problems listed in the article, using asynchronous code in the synchronous operators "breaks" Rx.

I'd consider using `OnErrorResumeNext()` for cleaning up resources asynchronously. `OnErrorResumeNext()` let's you specify an observable which will run after the first, regardless the reason it ended:

```
var myObservable = ...

myObservable
    .Subscribe( /* Business as usual */ );

Observable.OnErrorResumeNext(
        myObservable.Select(_ => Unit.Default),
        Observable.FromAsync(() => SomeCleanUpCodeAsync()))
    .Subscribe();
```

`myObservable` would preferably be a `ConnectableObservable` (e.g. `Publish()`) to prevent multiple subscriptions.

Comment: This takes care of the OnError scenario. However, I also need to clean up after OnCompleted. However, interesting that you are using Observable.FromAsync(). Is this the way to work around `async void`?

Comment: Contrary to what the name might imply `OnErrorResumeNext()` actually concats the second observable to the first one regardless whether the first observable errors. `OnErrorResumeNext()` behaves much like `Concat()`, but moves to the next observable on both *OnError* **and** *OnCompleted*

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. Will look into it.

Comment: `Finally` is actually the better semantic choice in this scenario.

Comment: Hi @Asti! The `Finally` invokes an `Action`, while the `OnErrorResumeNext` takes an observable as continuation. So the later is probably preferable as a substitute of `async using`.

Answer (score 2):

The method signature for `Finally` is

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Finally<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Action finallyAction
)
```

which expects an action, not a Task.

As an addendum, if you want to run something asynchronously, instead of async void, use `Task.Factory` methods inside the method so the intention is explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#Finally):

> The `Finally` extension method accepts an `Action` as a parameter. This `Action` will be invoked if the sequence terminates normally or erroneously, **or if the subscription is disposed of**.

(emphasis added)

This behavior cannot be replicated by a `Finally` operator that accepts a `Func<Task>` parameter, because of how the `IObservable<T>` interface is defined. Unsubscribing from an observable sequence is achieved by calling the [`Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose) method of the `IDisposable` subscription. This method is synchronous. And the whole Rx library is built on top of this interface. So even if you create an extension method `DisposeAsync` for `IDisposable`s, the built-in Rx operators (for example `Select`, `SelectMany`, `Where`, `Take` etc) will be unaware of its existence, and will not invoke it when they unsubscribe from their source sequence. A subscription chain of operators will be automatically unlinked by calling the synchronous `Dispose` method of the previous link as always.

Btw there has been an attempt to implement an asynchronous version of Rx ([AsyncRx](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/main/AsyncRx.NET)), that is built on top of the completely new interfaces that are shown below. This library [has not been released yet](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1118).

```
public interface IAsyncObserver<in T>
{
    ValueTask OnNextAsync(T value);
    ValueTask OnErrorAsync(Exception error);
    ValueTask OnCompletedAsync();
}

public interface IAsyncObservable<out T>
{
    ValueTask<IAsyncDisposable> SubscribeAsync(IAsyncObserver<T> observer);
}

public interface IAsyncDisposable
{
    public ValueTask DisposeAsync();
}
```