# Async Disposable.Create

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive, dispose

[Disposable.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.disposable.create(v=vs.103).aspx) require an `Action` as parameter. The `Action` is run when the Rx subscription is being disposed.

When disposing a Rx subscription I’d like to run some asynchronous clean up code, however using `async () =>` with `Action` is identical to `async void`, which I’d like to avoid. For more details on why I want to avoid this, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Is it possible to create something like a `Disposable.AsyncCreate`, which accepts `Func<Task>` rather than `Action`. If so how should I use it as part of a `CompositeDisposable`?

Or are there other patterns for dealing with asynchronous Disposal?

Comment: The IDisposable interface does not have any method returning a Task so how should calling Dispose wait for a task?

Comment: How this question is different from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205132/alternative-to-using-async-in-rx-finally ?

Comment: @Peter that is my understanding too. Still wondering if there is some way to accomplish this anyhow.

Comment: @JasperHBojsen - Why do you want to avoid `async () =>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've updated the question with a link explaining why I want to avoid `async void` which is the consequence of using `async () =>` with `Action`.

Comment: @JasperHBojsen - It doesn't have the same problem. I'll post some sample code to show.

Comment: I cover a couple of patterns [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/03/async-oop-6-disposal.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. I'm still not sure how good an idea it is:

```
public class DisposableAsync
{
    private readonly IDisposable _disposable; 
    private readonly Func<Task> _asyncDisposalAction;
    public DisposableAsync(IDisposable disposable, Func<Task> asyncDisposalAction)
    {
        _disposable = disposable;
        _asyncDisposalAction = asyncDisposalAction;
    }

    public Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        _disposable.Dispose();
        return _asyncDisposalAction();
    }
}

public static class DisposableAsyncExtensions
{
    public static DisposableAsync ToAsync(this IDisposable disposable, Func<Task> asyncDisposalAction)
    {
        return new DisposableAsync(disposable, asyncDisposalAction);
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
async Task Go()
{

    var o = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    var d = o
        .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: {i}"))
        .ToAsync(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: Dispose Beginning");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: Dispose Complete");
        });
    Console.Read();
    var t = d.DisposeAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: Outside task, waiting for dispose to complete");
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: Task Complete");

}
```

This solution wouldn't work with `using()` statements, and the class `DisposableAsync` should be robustified. Outside of that, I can't think of anything wrong with it, but I'm predisposed (ahem) against it though. Just feels kind of hacky.

Comment: Since you're not using a `using` you should still use a `try/finally` (as a `using` would) to ensure that the disposal happens even if there is an exception.

Comment: It's not exactly how I'd imagine a solution either but it's the closest to an answer I've come to too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `async () =>` has the problems you think it does.

Try this:

```
Action x = async () =>
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
        throw new Exception("Wait");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
};

var d = Disposable.Create(x);

d.Dispose();
```

It produces:

```
Hello
Wait
Goodbye
```

Comment: I suppose this is because everything inside the `Action` is wrapped around a try/catch, hence no exception risk being thrown outside the `Action` and hence there is no risk of such an exception crashing the process. I guess this could work, but it seems to me that it is not the most intuitively esthetical solution.

Comment: If you move the try catch outside the delegate to around the dispose, you get an unhandled exception on the process.

Comment: In the interests of fostering good coding practices, would you consider moving the `await` inside the `try { }` body? It's hard to overstate the importance of comprehensive exception handling in non-`Task` returning methods and delegates.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy - I was trying to make the error handling part of the code very distinct, but I would generally do it as you suggest.

Comment: It's not just about error handling semantics though.  Now the code is continuing on before finishing disposing of the resource.  That may well be problematic.