# Is it possible to use Rx "Using" operator with IAsyncDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

Is it possible to use the Using operator in Rx.Net with a resource that implements `IAsyncDisposable` rather than `IDisposable`? If not, is there some sort of workaround that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `Using` method that works with `IAsyncDisposable` objects:

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructs an observable sequence that depends on a resource object,
/// whose lifetime is tied to the resulting observable sequence's lifetime.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<TResult> Using<TResult, TResource>(
    Func<TResource> resourceFactory,
    Func<TResource, IObservable<TResult>> observableFactory)
    where TResource : IAsyncDisposable
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        TResource resource = resourceFactory();
        IObservable<TResult> observable;
        try { observable = observableFactory(resource); }
        catch (Exception ex) { observable = Observable.Throw<TResult>(ex); }

        Lazy<Task> lazyDisposeTask = new(() => resource.DisposeAsync().AsTask());
        IObservable<TResult> disposer = Observable
            .FromAsync(() => lazyDisposeTask.Value)
            .Select(_ => default(TResult))
            .IgnoreElements();

        return observable
            .Catch((Exception ex) => disposer.Concat(Observable.Throw<TResult>(ex)))
            .Concat(disposer)
            .Finally(() => lazyDisposeTask.Value.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
    });
}
```

This method has identical signature with the Rx [`Observable.Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229585(v=vs.103)) method (apart from the `where` clause), and it can be used in the same way.

This implementation takes care of all completion cases:

1. Successful completion: The `IAsyncDisposable` resource is disposed asynchronously by the `Concat` operator.
2. Completion with error: The `IAsyncDisposable` resource is disposed asynchronously by the `Catch` operator.
3. The sequence is unsubscribed before its completion: The `IAsyncDisposable` resource is disposed synchronously by the `Finally` operator. Disposing asynchronously the resource is not possible in this case, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205132/alternative-to-using-async-in-rx-finally/65511384#65511384).

Variant with asynchronous factory methods:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Using<TResult, TResource>(
    Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResource>> resourceFactoryAsync,
    Func<TResource, CancellationToken, Task<IObservable<TResult>>> observableFactoryAsync)
    where TResource : IAsyncDisposable
{
    return Observable.Create<TResult>(async (observer, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        TResource resource = await resourceFactoryAsync(cancellationToken);
        IObservable<TResult> observable;
        try { observable = await observableFactoryAsync(resource, cancellationToken); }
        catch { await resource.DisposeAsync(); throw; }

        Lazy<Task> lazyDisposeTask = new(() => resource.DisposeAsync().AsTask());
        IObservable<TResult> disposer = Observable
            .FromAsync(() => lazyDisposeTask.Value)
            .Select(_ => default(TResult))
            .IgnoreElements();

        return observable
            .Catch((Exception ex) => disposer.Concat(Observable.Throw<TResult>(ex)))
            .Concat(disposer)
            .Finally(() => lazyDisposeTask.Value.GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            .Subscribe(observer);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this looks great. I know my original question didn't specify this, but is it easy to extend your code so that the the resource factory returns `Task<TResource>`?

Comment: @jackdry sure, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Out of interest, is there a good reason for using `Lazy<Task>` rather than `Func<Task>` for "lazyDisposeTask"?

Comment: @jackdry yes. The `Lazy<Task>` ensures that the `DisposeAsync` will be called only once. Most real-world disposables tolerate being disposed multiple times, but better be safe than sorry. :-)

Comment: @jackdry FYI I fixed a bug in the implementation of both `Using` methods.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question (if okay!). Can you use `lazyDisposeTask.Value.Wait()` instead of`lazyDisposeTask.Value.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: @jackdry - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult

Comment: @jackdry it should be noted that the built-in `Observable.Using` method can cause an unhandled exception in case the `Dispose` invocation fails, and the same is true for the `Using` methods above. A relevant GitHub issue can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1632 "Observable.Using does not propagate exceptions from resource .Dispose method to stream"). Currently I don't know of a perfect solution to this problem.